# How to turn of the inner border for Facebook 'Like Button' in IE7/IE8?

Tags: facebook, button, hover, facebook-like

I have seen that even on big sites like CNN, etc. have it. I tried targeting the  element which showed up those edges in IE developer toolbar but it didn't work. 
Check out the link and hover over the 'like' button...it shows some kind of inner black border in all four corners.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Comment: in what browser you've experience that? I check in FF4 and don't the problem you describe.

Comment: @runrunforest Indeed, but the problem is quite noticeable in IE8... I'd paste a screenshot if I knew how.

Comment: @runrunforest just click on the link I posted and hover over Like button in IE 7 or IE 8..You will see a black inner border on all four edges of the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a bug in Facebook's CSS. Line 170 says

```
.connect_widget .like_button_no_like:hover .corner{background-position:10px 61px}
```

But it should in fact say `10px -95px`.

The other background-position values are probably wrong as well, but I don't know how to trigger them.

Comment: I have the same problem...I am unable to trigger it. I have seen it in a lot of websites but no one seems to have rectified it.

Comment: @Chitti That's because it would appear to be a Facebook bug. (It's not their only bug; another bug trips over IE's XSS detector.)